# How to Bundle Internal Dependencies with a Published SDK in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on a multi-module Gradle project named `layers` with the following structure and subprojects:

```
layers/
|- build.gradle.kts
|- settings.gradle.kts
|- buildSrc/
|  - build.gradle.kts
|- layers-sdk/
|  - build.gradle.kts
|- layers-api/
|  - build.gradle.kts
|- libs/
|  - build.gradle.kts
```

In settings.gradle.kts, the subprojects are included as follows:

```
include(
    "layers-sdk",
    "layers-api",
    "libs",
)
```

The layers-sdk module has dependencies on the other projects, specified in its build.gradle.kts like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(project(":libs"))
...
}
```

My goal is to publish `layers-sdk` to a Maven repository, including its internal dependencies (`libs` in this case), without publishing those internal dependencies separately to Maven. However, when I try to publish the SDK it add the internal dependencies on the generated POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.test.ep</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I attempted to bundle everything into the same jar and remove the references from the generated POM file with the following configuration:

```
tasks.jar {
  dependsOn(":libs")
  from(
    zipTree(project(":libs").tasks.getByName("jar").outputs.files.singleFile)
  )
  ... 
}
publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("main") {
      from(components["java"])
      version = scmVersion.version
      pom.withXml {
         <CODE TO EXCLUDE THE DEPENDENCIES> 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this approach resulted in an error when importing the SDK into the application:

```
   > Could not find com.test.ep:lib:0.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/test/ep/lib/0.0.1/lib-0.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project : > com.test:layers-sdk:0.21.0
```

Does anyone know how to correctly bundle internal dependencies with a published SDK in Gradle, so that the SDK can be used without separately publishing its internal dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies that are included in a Java library publication are those in the `apiElements` and `runtimeElements` configurations. These are the collections of dependencies used for (i) compiling against and (ii) executing the library respectively ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph)).

You can't add dependencies to these configurations directly. Instead, they obtain dependencies because they extend from the more familiar configurations of `api` (for `apiElements`) and `implementation` and `runtimeOnly` (for `runtimeElements`), to which you have added dependencies.

Therefore you can remove the dependencies from the publication (and thus the POM file) by removing these `extendsFrom` relations:

```
configurations {
    apiElements { setExtendsFrom(emptySet()) }
    runtimeElements { setExtendsFrom(emptySet()) }
}
```

Comment: At the end I made it work using shadowJar, but now it's bundling even the external dependencies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220362/gradle-selective-dependency-bundling-and-documentation-in-published-artifacts